# Unable to execute Javascript on certain websites via script injection

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-injection

I was trying to inject a React script into a website after page has loaded/

I was able to get it working on most of the websites like **https://google.com**, **https://discovercard.com**, **https://stackoverflow.com**, **https://capitalone.com**.

However, when I execute the same script in **https://chase.com** or **https://bankofamerica.com**, I get a reference error where I am transforming JSX using `Babel.transform` because `Babel` is undefined.

All the required scripts however are downloaded as can be seen in the network tab and the DOM.

Could someone please let me know if there any specific tag or attribute in the HTML that is preventing execution of Javascript on these websites. It seemed like banking websites do this to prevent external Javascript.

Here is the code I tried on the developer console

**NOTE:** Hello World! appears after 5 seconds because of the `setTimeout`

```
const react = document.createElement("script");
react.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"
document.body.appendChild(react);

const reactDom = document.createElement("script");
reactDom.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
document.body.appendChild(reactDom);

const babel = document.createElement("script");
babel.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"
document.body.appendChild(babel);

const rootDiv = document.createElement("div");
rootDiv.id = "app";
rootDiv.style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 999999";
document.body.appendChild(rootDiv);

setTimeout(() => {
  const babelScript = document.createElement("script");
  babelScript.type = "text/babel";

  const jsxCode = "ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello, world!</h1>, document.getElementById('app'));"

  const babelTransformCode = Babel.transform(jsxCode, { presets: ["react"] } ).code;

  eval(babelTransformCode);
}, 5000)
```

Comment: You should handle `onload` events for the scripts you're injecting, rather than having some arbitrary timeout.

Comment: Agree, but I am just trying to test it out to see what the difference could be.

Comment: That could be the difference.  I didn't just suggest it for a laugh :p

Comment: You mean the script is taking time to load? I don't think so, I tried a timeout of 25 seconds, still no dice, I can see the script being loaded from the network tab. Using `fetch` did not work either.

Comment: Well that was a suggestion, and you're probably right that it wouldn't fix it.  I'm actually not too bothered about trying to help you inject script into banking websites.  I'm just glad there's a log of this in case it's ever needed as evidence :)

Comment: Haha, not to worry, I am just trying to build an online editor for React. So was trying it on all the websites that I recalled at that moment.

Comment: My bet is on [CSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) not allowing foreign scripts - and `Babel` is just the first object from them that you're trying to use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two sites that aren't working are using requireJs, so that instead of loading the modules on window, they are getting loaded using `define`.

The easy thing to do, is just call `define = undefined` before the rest of your script and it will work just as it did with the rest of the sites.  For safety sake it appears that the UMD loader checks for exports and modules.exports as well, so you might want to set them to undefined as well.

```
define = undefined;
exports = undefined;
if (window.module) module.exports = undefined;
```

The libraries your are using are packed together using a Universal Module Definition.  That is so they can work with a wide variety of module loaders such as requireJs.  The UMD pattern looks for common variables defined by module loaders, so by setting these variables to undefined it causes the modules to be loaded globally and accessible to your scripts as written.

Comment: That is just super awesome! Thanks a lot! If possible could you please add a little bit more context? I don't know how requireJS works.